# stuck in uploading and downloading images using spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am developing one application for Hr Dept where

1. i want to show employee registration form having functionality to upload user details with user image up loader functionality
2. at the end of the form there is one more file up loader which can upload any file like doc file(for resume), images file(for educational certificate,experience letter scan copies)
3. after submitting form, i want to show one table with all user details and one link (view / Delete /Update new image) for showing uploaded files and images.

Uploading image code completed, but confuse in how to show(download) that image on jsp page(after clicking it should prompt me for save ,cancel,open)

can anybody guide me on the same...

(I have accomplished uploading image through directly importing image into blob in oracle db. Is this ok???)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the uploaded image somewhere (in the database is fine), then add an `<img src="...">` tag to your JSP that refers to the image. Then add a servlet to serve up the image (that corresponds to the `src` in the tag), like here: http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2007/04/imageservlet.html

Comment: :I got an advice "One should not import images directly into the db it will increase db load ,when you are uploading hundreds of image instead use folder to store images and store absolute path of that image into database".

Comment: Respectfully disagree with whoever said that. Your application becomes less portable and testable once you start using more than one persistent store. 'db load' consists mostly of disk access, which is equally the case when you store the images in a folder.

Comment: :As per my knowledge if i use blob and read that content using byte[] and if suppose image size is around 2.5 MB * 100 files then it will take some time because we have to read data in bytestream format .Please tell me if i am wrong. I don't know much about image reading and writing. this is my first module which will have this functionality. i want to make my application fast and secure,i can not compromise with either of the them.

Comment: There is some debate on which approach is best, you can google for more info. Make sure you test the speed rather than relying on assertions. Remember: make it work, make it right, make it fast (in that order).